# Django runserver

Tags: python, django

When I run my django server this occurs:

## Page not found (404)

Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/

Using the URLconf defined in `djproject.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. admin/

The current path, `myapp/`, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have `DEBUG = True` in your Django settings file. Change that to `False`, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

This is my djproject `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('myapp/',
               include('myapp.urls'))]
```

this is myapp `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [path('', views.home, name='my app-home')]
```

my app `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return (HttpResponse('<h1>Hello</h1>'), )
```

Comment: make sure you listed `myapp` in `settings.py's installed_apps`. `urls.py` seems fine.

Comment: I fixed it and it did the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the comma from the end of the line HttpResponse

Comment: There is also another mistake in `name` of `path` in `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: Is it in the urls.py myapp?